# How to make a reset button to iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, reset

There are four NavigationController views connected by segues.
In three views I input variables by UITextField's and in the last I have label with counting result.
I try to make a button, that reset application to "0%" and opens `initialViewController`.
How could I do this?

Comment: Not sure about the "0%" part but for the initalViewController you can do this `self.navigationController?.popToViewControoler(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first)`

Comment: Hello, You say when click on button application data is totally reset. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Unwind method.

1) Create @IBAction method in first screen to return.

2) Connect button on last screen to Exit and choose method name from first step.

3) Be sure that segue name and action is equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Display two option used with your needed.

Option 1:

If you embed navigation controller to your view controller then you can use this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController")
let viewcontrollers = self.navigationController.viewControllers
viewcontrollers.removeLast()
viewcontrollers.append(vc)
self.navigationControllers?.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers, animate: true)
```

Option 2:

```
@IBAction func resetToOriginalState(sender: UIButton { 

    // this line is wrong, you shouldn't have UIButton in here
    self.resetToOriginalState (sender: UIButton)

    // the line should read
    self.resetToOriginalState (sender: sender)
}
```

I hope above option is helpful.